# -webkit-background-clip: text and vertically centred text

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm looking to vertically centre an element inside of a full-page element with a background image, that contains background-clipped text. Using `-webkit-background-clip: text` and the corresponding IE fallback works just fine for the clipping, but each and every time I try to centre the box using `display: inline-block` or `position: absolute` the text immediately disappears.

```css
body {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.box {
  height: calc(100vh - 2rem);
  border: 1px solid;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.align {
  /* to right-align the text box */
  text-align: right;
  
  /* uncomment below to see the issue */
  /* display: inline-block; */
}

.title {
  /* Duplicated here for Safari */
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  color: yellow;
  
  margin: 0;
  font: bold 6rem/1 sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<article class="box">
  <div class="align">
    <h1 class="title">The Title</h1>
</article>
```

I've created [a Codepen with an example](https://codepen.io/benjibee/pen/wqxZmz?editors=0100). If you uncomment `display: inline-block` on the `.align` class or attempt to vertically centre it with `position: absolute` and `transform` for example, the text disappears.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was indeed a known issue, and was resolved in Chrome 63!

Comment: Is it really resolved? I still have this issue in Chrome 65.